# How to Show Previous page selected item in flip view control in another page in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, flipview

I want to show the grid view selected item in flip view control.The control was placed in another page.
Please tell me how to get this?

I tried the below code:
Previous Page grid view item click event:

```
private void PhotoGrid_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemid = ((flipimage)e.ClickedItem);
            flipimage s = new flipimage() { ImageUrl = itemid.ImageUrl, Title = itemid.Title };
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FlipPage), s);
        }
```

Second Page :

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            //IEnumerable<flipimage> images = from img in xdoc.Descendants("Image") select new flipimage(img.Element("ImageTitle").Value, img.Element("ImageUrl").Value);

            flipimage s = (flipimage)e.Parameter;
           string url =  s.ImageUrl;
           flipviewcontrol.Items.Add(url);

           //flipviewcontrol.DataContext = images;
        }



<FlipView HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="flipviewcontrol" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="762" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1360" x:Name="imagecontrol"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>

        </FlipView>
```

Please tell me how to show previuos page images in flip view another page in windows 8?

Comment: are you able to get image url on you flipview control page in your OnNavigatedTo method.. ?

Comment: yes i am getting image url how to show image url to filp  and my grid contain 10 items how to show all items one by one ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i have made a standard sample to work with your problem..you are binding your flipview Itemssource to Images ( collection of strings i think in your case ..) so first make a ObservableCollection named Images..like this.in your page.cs( or in your view model if you are using in that case you have to send message to your viewmodel.) like this..

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; set; }
```

in your page constructor do this..

```
public BasicPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();


        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

and when you navigate to this page just add string url to your collection it will automatically update your flipview..i have taken a predefined string(i think it's fine)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        //IEnumerable<flipimage> images = from img in xdoc.Descendants("Image") select new flipimage(img.Element("ImageTitle").Value, img.Element("ImageUrl").Value);

        string url = "/Assets/teacher-symbol.png";
        Images.Add(url);
        Images.Add(url);
        Images.Add(url);
        Images.Add(url);
        Images.Add(url);
        Images.Add(url);
      //  flipviewcontrol.Items.Add(url);

        //flipviewcontrol.DataContext = images;
    }
```

now change your flipview control like this..

```
<FlipView HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="flipviewcontrol" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Grid.Row="1">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding}" Height="762" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1360" x:Name="imagecontrol"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>

    </FlipView>
```

hope this help..for any query comment below..

for your query..you have to do this..for your other images..

```
private void flipviewcontrol_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "/Assets/usericondash.png";
        Images.Add(url);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .Every thing is fine but in OnNavigatedTo() method i am getting only selected item image url how to show other images when click on next in filpview?how to do that?

Comment: just add the new images url to this collection..on your flipview selectionChangedEvents..i have updated My code.

Comment: can we show the images in the order of they were placed in gridview.In grid view images are placed in particular order.randomly i am clicking the item and sending that url to next page showing in flipview.whenever click on selected change event of filp view need to show after the items of selected item as they were placed in grid view.can you give idea for this?in selected change how to add after the selected item image urls.when ever back click on filp need to show it's previuos all items.

Comment: ohh..i just forgot your comment..as i went for the lunch..i am really sorry..for that..